# How to perform the Google App gcloud app deploy commands locally

Tags: google-app-engine

I can perform file uploads and sync commands locally with stuff like this:

```
 "deploy": "npm run build && gsutil cp src/app.yaml gs://quantumjs-site && gsutil -m cp -r dist  gs://quantumjs-site && npm run remote sync",
 "sync": "gsutil rsync -r gs://quantumjs-site gs://staging.fluid-griffin-211109.appspot.com/test-app",
```

But I have to log on to the console (via the website) to do deploy like this:

[image]

Can I do this locally

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You do the commands from the command line. (Terminal for Mac, CMD prompt for Windows)

Comment: I tried **ssh staging.fluid-griffin-211109.appspot.com**, but nothing happened.